# When I'm in pose mode, I am able to select non-bone objects. How do I disable this

Tags: modeling

So, when I'm in pose mode, I can select actually anything. I find it annoying, because I select things without having the intention to. When I select something in Pose mode(a non-bone object), it changes to Object mode. Once I select one of the bones again, it changes from Object mode to Pose mode. As you can see in the pictures below, I'm able to go from Pose mode to Object mode by selecting any non-Bone object. I haven't tried anything yet. Btw, I'm a beginner in Blender and I would like a detailed awnser.

[image: In Pose mode][image: From Pose mode to Object mode]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want the selection to act this way, enable the *Edit > Lock Object Modes* option:

[image]